# Passing a variable from Gesture Recognizer function to an IBAction

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, return-type, ibaction

I have a simple app with a `CollectionView` and items in it.
On long pressing a `cell` a popup `UIView` appears with a `TextField` and an option to save it in the `array` corresponding to the `cell`.

Here is the code (The `buttons` and `gestures` have been added correctly in `viewDidLoad()` method):

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {
var longPressedPoint: CGPoint?

public var rowOfLongPressedItem: Int? = nil

func handleLongPress(longPressRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)  -> Int      {
    print("LONG PRESS Gesture Recognized")
    notePopup.hidden = false
    longPressedPoint =  longPressRecognizer.locationInView(longPressRecognizer.view)
    var indexPathOfLongPressedCell = self.itemCollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(longPressedPoint!)
    rowOfLongPressedItem = (indexPathOfLongPressedCell?.row)
    print("rowOfLongPressedItem -> .\(rowOfLongPressedItem)")
    return rowOfLongPressedItem!
}

func saveNoteButtonTapped(rowOfLongPressedItem: Int) {
    print("rowOfLongPressedItem when Save button is tapped -> .\(rowOfLongPressedItem)")       

    //Can’t go further down as rowOfLongPressedItem is NOT available from “handleLongPress” function…

    var selectedItem = ItemsList[rowOfLongPressedItem]
    selectedItem.counts += 1
    var latest = selectedItem.counts - 1
    selectedItem.timestamp.append(NSDate())
    selectedItem.note.append(noteTextField.text)
    ItemsList[rowOfLongPressedItem] = selectedItem
    print(".\(selectedItem.title) has been tapped .\(selectedItem.counts)")
    print("The latest tap on .\(selectedItem.title) is at .\(selectedItem.timestamp[latest])")
    print("The note .\(noteTextField.text) has been added")
    notePopup.hidden = true
}
}
```

Tried solving the issue in couple of ways:

- Defining a variable in the View Controller hoping that the function will return the value and save it in global variable. 
  But, later found from Apple that 
  "A function cannot have a higher access level than its parameter types and return type, because the function could be used in situations where its constituent types are not available to the surrounding code."
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html
- I tried putting the Button's Selector function code inside the Long Press Gesture Function so that it's return value is easily available. But, I am unable to call the Selector function as it is inside another function.
- Also, I tried returning the value of Long Press Gesture Function and using it in IBAction of the Save button. However, for this I need call `handleLongPress` again and then the `longPressedPoint` is detected as inside Save button. Hence, the `indexPathOfLongPressedCell` is `nil` and the app crashes.

Can someone please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the selected cell's row and assigns it to a global variable `rowOfLongPressedItem`, you don't need to let `handleLongPress` returns an Int.

**NOTE**: This is a Swift 3 code (with the same concept):

```
public var rowOfLongPressedItem: Int? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //...

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.assignRowOfLongPressedItem))

    itemCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

    //...
}

func assignRowOfLongPressedItem(longPressRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let longPressedPoint = longPressRecognizer.location(in: longPressRecognizer.view)
    var indexPathOfLongPressedCell = self.itemCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: longPressedPoint)
    rowOfLongPressedItem = (indexPathOfLongPressedCell?.row)
    // if you long press the first row -for example-, the output should be: "rowOfLongPressedItem -> .Optional(0)"
    print("rowOfLongPressedItem -> .\(rowOfLongPressedItem)")
}
```

Also, you don't need to let `saveNoteButtonTapped` to take `rowOfLongPressedItem` parameter. Note that `rowOfLongPressedItem` is optional, you should make sure it is not still nil (you can use [Early Exit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525) approach):

```
func saveNoteButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        guard let selectedCellRow = rowOfLongPressedItem else {
            print("rowOfLongPressedItem is nil!!")
            return
        }

        print("rowOfLongPressedItem when Save button is tapped -> .\(selectedCellRow)")
        var selectedItem = ItemsList[selectedCellRow]

        selectedItem.counts += 1
        var latest = selectedItem.counts - 1
        selectedItem.timestamp.append(NSDate())
        selectedItem.note.append(noteTextField.text)
        ItemsList[row] = selectedItem
        print(".\(selectedItem.title) has been tapped .\(selectedItem.counts)")
        print("The latest tap on .\(selectedItem.title) is at .\(selectedItem.timestamp[latest])")
        print("The note .\(noteTextField.text) has been added")
        notePopup.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: This is even better. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you alerting me to make sure that `rowOfLongPressedItem` is not `nil`.

Comment: Though this code works, I am trying to understand why it works.
Based on "A function cannot have a higher access level than its parameter types and return type, because the function could be used in situations where its constituent types are not available to the surrounding code." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html
this code should not work, isn't it. How can `assignRowOfLongPressedItem` save `rowOfLongPressedItem` which is a global variable?

Comment: @Ahmad It seems you missed this one -> `ItemsList[row] = selectedItem` ;)

Answer (score 0):

`rowOfLongPressedItem` is available to both functions. You don't need to make it a parameter of `saveNoteButtonTapped`.

```
var rowOfLongPressedItem: Int? = nil

func handleLongPress(longPressRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)  -> Int      {
    print("LONG PRESS Gesture Recognized")
    notePopup.hidden = false
    longPressedPoint =  longPressRecognizer.locationInView(longPressRecognizer.view)
    var indexPathOfLongPressedCell = self.itemCollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(longPressedPoint!)
    rowOfLongPressedItem = (indexPathOfLongPressedCell?.row)
    print("rowOfLongPressedItem -> .\(rowOfLongPressedItem)")
    return rowOfLongPressedItem!
}

func saveNoteButtonTapped() {

    guard let row = rowOfLongPressedItem else {
        return // rowOfLongPressedItem was nil
    }

    print("rowOfLongPressedItem when Save button is tapped -> .\(row)")
    var selectedItem = ItemsList[row]

    selectedItem.counts += 1
    var latest = selectedItem.counts - 1
    selectedItem.timestamp.append(NSDate())
    selectedItem.note.append(noteTextField.text)
    ItemsList[row] = selectedItem
    print(".\(selectedItem.title) has been tapped .\(selectedItem.counts)")
    print("The latest tap on .\(selectedItem.title) is at .\(selectedItem.timestamp[latest])")
    print("The note .\(noteTextField.text) has been added")
    notePopup.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not sure if the `rowOfLongPressedItem`. Here is the output for my existing code
`rowOfLongPressedItem -> .Optional(2)
rowOfLongPressedItem when Save button is tapped -> .140667464596544
fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb) `

Also, I tried adding the guard statement, but getting this error"
`Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'`

Please help

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. I didn't remove the parameter in `saveNoteButtonTapped()` function
However, one small change here is:
`func saveNoteButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) `
I have made this change and marked your response as answer.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @EcoApps You're welcome:) Why do you need the sender parameter? you're not using it anywhere in the function

Comment: @EcoApps Is this an IBAction function?

Comment: No, it's a selector function of a UIButton

Comment: @EcoApps You can remove the parameter from the selector if you don't need it like this: #selector(saveNoteButtonTapped)